# Little script/VB.NET code that will prevent auto-logout in Windows 2003 server edition

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2003, logout

I have a Windows 2003 server that we regularly RDP in to monitor some programs that we set up to run on the machine automatically.

However, the server will automatically log me out after a few minutes of inactivity. Unfortunately the server admin (who has the admin rights to the server, which I don't) is reluctant to remove such restrictions "for security reasons".

Therefore, instead of me trying to fill up 10000 piece of paper getting a security exemption, I am just wondering if there is any tiny program that I can run on the server (either a script or some VB.NET code) that will trick the server into thinking I am constantly typing something even though I am not (For example, as if I am moving my mouse cursor once every 30 seconds or type any letter then erase it in notepad)?

Note that since I do not have admin rights, any installation is certainly out of question, and the script, if any, can not require admin rights to run properly.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in a vbs ...  I am not sure it will work ... but it is worth a try..

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
         WshShell.Run "notepad"
         WScript.Sleep 100
         WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"

Do While True
    WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
    WshShell.SendKeys "1234"

    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
    WshShell.SendKeys "{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}{BACKSPACE}"

    WScript.Sleep 1000

loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your super-fast response! I will give it a try on Monday when I get to work and let you know :) Thanks once again!

Comment: I tested this on my machine and it appears to keep the screensaver from firing... you might make the sleep longer... also be sure to run this from the console using cscript... or you will end up with a process running that you will not be able to kill except through taskmanager...

Comment: ex:  
cscript KeepMeLoggedIn.vbs

Comment: mmmm...so I can't Ctrl + C to stop it? :)

Comment: if you run it from the console you can... ctrl+C  if not then it is just a process running and you would have to go find the WScript process running and kill it... if you run it from the console ie... start-->run  ... type cmd   .. then type "cscript {nameofscript.vbs}" it will run in the console and you can either just kill the cmd window to kill the process or like you said ctrl+c

Comment: Thanks a lot for your super-fast response!

Comment: Thanks for the answer jsobo, however the problem with this script is that whenever the notepad app lost its focus, it will press backspace on whatever other application that is active, causing quite a bit of headache...is there anyway we could make sure the sendkey is "locked" to that notepad instance? thanks a lot!

Comment: I updated the script to reset focus on the notepad... but if you are actually using the computer this will get quite annoying but then again if you are using the computer then you wouldn't need the script...

Comment: Do you think it make more sense if somehow we can assign a reference to the notepad object (THE one) and run all these only if it is activated? thanks!